# Will the more gnome extensions and more cursors and themes i use make my computer slower?

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.10, gnome-tweaks

I know this is a lame question and I hope you understand, so recently I have been having fun with gnome-shell and everything and I have been messing around with themes and I wanted to know if it makes my computer slower if you know an answer please answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that adds additional work or demands additional resources from your hardware can slow your system down.

Beyond this, your question is purely hypothetical and case-dependent.  There wouldn't be any more detailed answer to your question that would be fact-based.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info @Nmath!